# Compatibility of new MacBook Pro 13 with my Windows 10 equipment

Tags: macbook

I've been using Windows equipment since Amiga went away.
Now I want to try a new MacBook Pro 13 but I'm concerned about it's compatiblity with my printer, wi-fi, desk top ...
Will I be able to connect the Mac with my "smart" Samsung TV?
Will my printer (HP Photosmart 7520) work with the Mac?
Will my current Wi-Fi setup work with the Mac?
Will the Mac communicate (exchange photos etc.)with my Windows 10 desk top?
Thanks for the help!
jake35

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Probably yes.

For specific hardware devices such as your TV and printer you can easily Google connecting/managing/using them with Apple computer products. Most devices should work just fine with either brand of device.

WiFi is a standard that works across computer types. Just like a Windows computer and an Apple computer can both connect at Starbucks, they should both be able to connect to home WiFi.

Exchanging photos will probably require a utility or third-party system, but shouldn't be difficult. There are ways to set up network shares on the systems that can see each other, or you could use DropBox or Google Drive, which both have both Windows and Apple clients, or you could set up a network-based home storage device which will work with both.

Comment: If one of the answers solves your problem, please mark it as the correct answer. If they do not answer your questions completely, please let us know how they do not work so that we can improve them and get you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the HP Photosmart 7520 works with macOS 10.6 and above.

WiFi is a standard that works across all platforms, so you won't have any problems there.

You can also set up a network or just use file sharing to share content (such as photos) between Mac and Windows, or use third party cloud services such as DropBox and Google Drive (as @music2myear also mentioned).

In terms of your Samsung TV, your question isn't clear as to what you mean by connecting to it. You can stream etc to it (via an Apple TV for instance), and you'd be able to connect to it using an appropriate cable (e.g. a HDMI cable). However, you may need to purchase a cable and/or adaptor depending on your actual model of TV and the actual model of MacBook Pro (different models have different ports).